# ttk.Notebook different grid size on each tab

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, ttk

I'm creating a GUI using Tkinter and I've created multiple tabs using ttk.Notebook(). On Tab1 there are a few Labels and Entry boxes, and on Tab2 I have a matplotlib plot. I am using the grid layout manager exclusively.

The problem I've run into is that when I place the plot on Tab2 (in row=0) it seems to have increased the size of row 0 on Tab 1 as well, creating a lot of space between the 2 labels (which should be right on top of one another).

(Very) Minimal version of the code is below. What am I missing? How can I independently control the row height on each tab so widgets on Tab2 don't set the row height on Tab1? Thanks in advance for the help.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")


class MainGUI(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.title('Title')
        self.geometry('750x500')

        # Adds tabs to main window
        self.nb = ttk.Notebook(self)
        self.nb.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=5, rowspan=4, sticky='NESW')
        self.tab1 = ttk.Frame(self.nb)
        self.nb.add(self.tab1, text='Tab1')
        self.tab2 = ttk.Frame(self.nb)
        self.nb.add(self.tab2, text='Tab2')

        # defines a grid 10 x 5 cells in the main window & tabs
        rows = 0
        cols = 0
        while rows < 10:
            while cols < 5:
                self.rowconfigure(rows, weight=1)
                self.columnconfigure(cols, weight=1)
                self.tab1.rowconfigure(rows, weight=1)
                self.tab1.columnconfigure(cols, weight=1)
                self.tab2.rowconfigure(rows, weight=1)
                self.tab2.columnconfigure(cols, weight=1)
                cols += 1
            rows += 1

        self.tab1Label = tk.Label(self.tab1, text="This is a Label")
        self.tab1Label.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky='NW')
        self.tab1Label2 = tk.Label(self.tab1, text="This is also a Label")
        self.tab1Label2.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky='NW')

        self.makePlot()

    def makePlot(self):
        f = Figure(figsize=(5, 5), dpi=100)
        a = f.add_subplot(111)
        a.plot([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], [5, 6, 1, 3, 8, 9, 3, 5])
        canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f, self.tab2)
        canvas.draw()
        canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(column=2, row=0, columnspan=2, sticky='NSEW')


def main():
    MainGUI().mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Remove `self.makePlot()` in your testcase, you will see there ist **no** relationship.

Comment: @stovfl - Yes, I did notice this after posting my question. In my full code I did not have the issue with the large row height on Tab1 until I added the plot though, so I assumed they were somehow related. Any actual advice on how I can control the row height on Tab1?

Comment: Did you real need the same `grid` layout on `root == self.` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you comment out this line:

```
self.tab1.rowconfigure(rows, weight=1)
```

You will notice the issue is gone. Your problem comes from your `while` loop. I can also say that your `while` loop is not doing what you think it is doing. You only configure row 0 to have a weight and this is why your 2nd label is sitting on the bottom of the screen.

Lets break down what your `while` statement is doing.

On the first loop where `row = 0` you tell the loop to do another `while` loop based on `cols`. So it then does `rowconfigure(0, weight=1)` 5 times and also does `columnconfig(0 through 4, weight=1)`. However the problem comes on the next loop. Because `cols = 5` now your 2nd while loop will always be false and therefor never configures rows 1 through 9.

What you should do is something like this.

```
for i in range(10):
    self.tab1.rowconfigure(i, weight=1)
    self.tab2.rowconfigure(i, weight=1)
for i in range(5):
    self.tab1.columnconfigure(i, weight=1)
    self.tab2.columnconfigure(i, weight=1)
```

This way you can be sure to apply a weight to all rows and columns.

Comment: Thanks Mike. I had thought about this at some point, but obviously got confused when going through the logic of the nested while loops. Your suggestion works like a charm.